# How to implement jwt token base authentication with custom policy schema for authorization in .net core?

Tags: .net-core, jwt, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to create a playground app in .NET Core 3.1 by trying to implement the jwt token based authentication and would like **to use my custom policy schema** (scary?). I was able to do this pretty comfortable with customized filter attributes which was derived from `AuthorizeAttribute` in .NET Framework, but having hard time with .NET Core. Because I was using `OnAuthorization` hook  and was capturing the `HttpActionContext`, resolving the token and checking role policy etc... But now I am using `IAuthorizationHandler` which I didn't have a chance to make it work in my desired way so far. I read MANY examples, articles but yet I couldn't find same approach to what I am trying to do.

*(PS: When I search for hours and cant find similar approach that also makes me feel pretty nervous as I might be going on complete wrong route, or trying to re-invent the wheel.. Let's see if I am..)*

I also looked for the [IdendityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/index.html) (yet many people find it way easier to manage - but seems an overkill to me for what I am trying to do. Blame me if I  am wrong.)

What I did so far is, I am able to create a token successfully when user logs in. Here is the code:
***(if you want to see what I am exactly asking, please directly scroll to the end but if you are going to answer please read through)***

Behind the scene, I am using [salted-hash password](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) in db as well as [key-strecthing](https://blogs.getcertifiedgetahead.com/key-stretching/) with [PBKDF2 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) ( I do appreciate any security concern)

My GenerateToken function:

```
[HttpPost("token")]
public IActionResult GenerateToken(UserCredentialDto userCredentialDto) {
    bool isValidUser = _appUserManager.IsValidCredentials(userCredentialDto);

    if (!isValidUser) {
        return BadRequest("invalid user/pass combination");
    }

    // assume I am getting all the roles that user has and add them in claims.
    var claims = _appUserManager.GetUserClaims(userCredentialDto); 
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(_jwtSettings.Key);
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: _jwtSettings.Issuer, audience: _jwtSettings.Audience, claims: claims, expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(StaticAFUConfigHelper.TokenExpirationInMinutes), signingCredentials: creds);

    return Ok(new {
        token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)
    });
}
```

General background: *(I am not using aspnet identity tables)*

- Each user has roles (I have a table as Role and xref table as UserRole)
- Roles have policies (I have a table as Policy and xref table as
  RolePolicy)

General workflow is:

- User requests token (simple - enter username and password on login
  page)
- If valid credentials, then generate a token to user which includes the user roles in claims.
- Once user makes a request to an API method, check if **any** of the
  `role` that user has, including the **required** `policy` to be able to
  make that request!

So "basically", I would like to get the token (sent the token along with the request or in claims) , resolve it, check user has what I am looking for (specific policy etc..) and proceed based on that.

And in the `startup.cs`

```
//Authentication
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options = >{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "my issuer",
        ValidAudience = "my audience",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String("assume this is my secret key"))
    };
    options.SaveToken = true;
});

 // this part I'm also not sure as if I have 100s of policies, 
 // would all of them has to be defined here?
 // and how I specifically assign this to an api method! Anyways please keep reading if you dont mind
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                options.AddPolicy("CanReadData", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new NeedsPolicyAttribute(PolicyEnum.CanReadData))));
```

Then I created `TokenValidationHandler` which is derived from AuthorizationHandler with my custom policy attribute `NeedsPolicyAttribute` ..

NeedsPolicyAttribute :

```
 public class NeedsPolicyAttribute: IAuthorizationRequirement {
    public PolicyEnum RequiredPolicy {
        get;
    }
    public NeedsPolicyAttribute(PolicyEnum requiredPolicy) {
        RequiredPolicy = requiredPolicy;
    }
}
```

And the HandleRequirementAsync is :

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, NeedsPolicyAttribute requirement) {
    var myToken = "1234567889"; // just hardcoded for example - assume I got the JWT from the context.

    SecurityToken validatedToken;
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    // assume there was no exception and I was able to validate the token which is a valid token...
    var user = handler.ValidateToken(myToken, _jwtSettings.TokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);

    // ************************........ATTENTION HERE....... *****************
    // I would like to check if the user has a role and which includes the policy which was required by the api method.
    //if so then, 
    context.Succeed(requirement);

    //if not then
    context.Fail();

    // and finally
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And my example API method is decorated as:

```
  [HttpGet][Route("get/{id}")]
  [Authorize("CanReadData")] // THIS JUST LETS ME TRIGGER MY CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE TO BE CAPTURED BY HandleRequirementAsync BUT I CAN ONLY PROVIDE HARDCODE STRING
   public ActionResult < AppUserDto > GetAppUser(int id) {
     return _appUserManager.Get(id);
}
```

**What I actually want to do is, decorate my API Method with the required policy and validate if the given token *has a claim with a role which includes that required policy*.**

Something like below:

```
  [HttpGet][Route("get/{id}")]
  [MyPolicyAttrubute(MyPolicyEnum.CanDoBlaBla)] // I want to capture this in HandleRequirementAsync if possible and compare with my user claims..
   public ActionResult < AppUserDto > GetAppUser(int id) {
     return _appUserManager.Get(id);
}
```

Breathtaking questions:

- Am I trying to re-invent the wheel?
- Even if I am, is there any obvious bad practices with this approach?
- Any other/better recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours, I was able to make this work. So I just wanted to post this as an answer to my question, but my "*breathtaking questions*" (see at the end of my question above) are still. So be aware this solution does not guarantee any of those concerns.

One of the concerns I had in the code piece in `StartUp.cs` in my question above was :

```
// if I have 100s of policies, would all of them have to be defined here?
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                options.AddPolicy("CanReadData", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new NeedsPolicyAttribute(PolicyEnum.CanReadData))));
```

because the example codes were adding them one by one as hardcoded string which was bothering me since the beginning as I want to use Enum not hardcoded values. And I didn't want to add many lines in `Startup.cs` which was also needed to be updated everytime I add a new policy to application.

So that was easy actually. All I did was:

I wrote an extension to get all the enum values like below:

```
 public static class EnumUtils {
  public static IEnumerable < T > GetAllEnumValues < T > () {
   return System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast < T > ();
  }
 }
```

So I was able to use it like below. So that lets me use any new created Policy enum value on top of API methods as an attribute without touching `StartUp.cs` now.

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options => {
     // add all the policies to option to be able to use in ExtendedAuthorizeAttribute on api methods.
     foreach(var policyEnum in EnumUtils.GetAllEnumValues < PolicyEnum > ())
           options.AddPolicy(policyEnum.ToString(), policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ExtendedAuthorizeAttribute(policyEnum)));
    });
```

Then I added the policies that user has:

```
public List < Claim > GetUserClaims(AuthRequestDto authRequestDto) {
    var userRoles = _unitOfWork.Roles.GetUserRoles(authRequestDto.UserId);
    var policies = userRoles.SelectMany(x = >x.RolePolicies.Where(p = >p.Policy.IsActive).Select(y = >y.Policy.Name)).Distinct().ToList();

    var claims = new List < Claim > ();
    policies.ForEach(policy = >claims.Add(new Claim("UserPolicy", policy)));
    claims.Add(new Claim("Id", authRequestDto.UserId.ToString()));
    return claims;
}
```

And attached them to my token so once user make a request with that token, I can resolve it and check against the required policy on api method.

Then I created new `Attribute` as `ExtendedAuthorizeAttribute` which derives from `AuthroizeAttribute` AND implements the `IAuthorizationRequirement`

So 2 things here: 
I derived my custom attribute from `AuthroizeAttribute` because I want it to triggered automatically for authorization to check if user has the required policy for that api method.
And I implemented `IAuthorizationRequirement` because this lets me use my attribute as "requirement" in `HandleRequirementAsync` method.

So the attribute I created was:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extended Authorize Attribute is derived from Authorize Attribute
/// also implements IAuthorizationRequirement.
/// Deriving from AuthorizeAttribute accepts only string for policy names
/// By using this extension class, it let's me use Policy Enum then it converts it to string
/// before passing it to AuthorizeAttribute which was not possible in controller.  
/// </summary>
public class ExtendedAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute,
IAuthorizationRequirement {
    public ExtendedAuthorizeAttribute(PolicyEnum policyEnum = PolicyEnum.General) : base(policyEnum.ToString()) {}
}
```

And `TokenValidationHandler` became like below:

```
public class TokenValidationHandler: AuthorizationHandler < ExtendedAuthorizeAttribute > {
    private readonly JwtSettings _jwtSettings;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public TokenValidationHandler(JwtSettings jwtSettings, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) {
        _jwtSettings = jwtSettings;
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ExtendedAuthorizeAttribute requirement) {

        // injected the IHttpContextAccessor to get the token from the request.
        var rawToken = !_contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization") ? string.Empty: _contextAccessor ? .HttpContext ? .Request ? .Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawToken)) {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var token = ScrubToken(rawToken);
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        try {
            // validates the given token and returns claims principal for user if validated.
            var user = handler.ValidateToken(token, _jwtSettings.TokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken _);

            // Check if UserPolicies claims include the required the policy 
            if (IsRequiredPolicyExistOnUser(user.Claims ? .ToList(), requirement)) {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            } else {
                context.Fail();
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            // TODO: Logging!
            context.Fail();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private bool IsRequiredPolicyExistOnUser(List < Claim > userClaims, ExtendedAuthorizeAttribute requirement) {
        return userClaims != null && userClaims.Any() && userClaims.Where(x = >x.Type == "UserPolicy").Any(c = >c.Value == requirement.Policy.ToString());
    }

    private string ScrubToken(string rawToken) {
        return rawToken.Replace("Bearer ", "");
    }
}
```

And finally I was able to use this on my api methods like below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("get/{id}")]
[ExtendedAuthorize(PolicyEnum.CanReadData)]
public ActionResult < AppUserDto > GetAppUser(int id) {
    return _appUserManager.Get(id);
}
```

and it worked just like the way I wanted. But again, *breathtaking questions* are still as of now!